# Hard drive making strange sound

Tags: linux, hard-disk, acer

It sounds like the HDD is put into a power saving/sleep mode, spun down, but immediately started up again, and then this repeated 3-4 times, very quickly.
How could I find out what this exactly is, and what causes it?

Answer (score 0):

If the drive has *S.M.A.R.T* then you could check what it reports with `smartmontools`

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
sudo smartctl
```

or

```
sudo gsmartcontrol
```

UPDATE:

To narrow the problem down I would recommend to boot up from LIVE CD/USB and see if to happens or not. It it doesn't happen in LIVE CD/USB that means that the issue is related to a software, i.e. your installed OS. Otherwise I tend to think it is may be related to a hardware.

Comment: The tests reported no error, however it happens while booted up from LIVE USB.

Comment: Did you try to update BIOS to the latest version?